# Какие языки программирования подходят для скрипта, работающего в реальном времени, в web'е?

Tags: realtime

1. Скрипт должен работать в течение нескольких часов без перебоев.
2. Берет на себя роль демона, который запускает команды, установленные им же в определенные временные точки. Выполнение команд с точностью до заданной секунды.
3. Желательно с возможностью привязать это дело к php, потому что основная часть написана на нем.

Я бы выбрал для этого дела cron, но он выполняется не чаще, чем раз в минуту, костыли писать не хочется, поэтому нужно что-то подобное, но с возможностью выполнения каждую секунду.

Какие языки программирования могут подойти для подобных задач?

P.S. - Возможна также альтернатива cron'у, но в однопотоке (следующий запуск не сработает, пока не завершится предыдущий) и с точностью до секунды.

Comment: Подойдет ли Node.js для таких целей?

Comment: Подойдёт абсолютно любой язык (хоть php, хоть nodejs), и cron тут ни при чём

Comment: И как вы предлагаете сделать это на том же php? Он вряд ли создан, чтобы работать на постоянке часа на 2 в ожидании новых запланированных запусков каких-то методов.

Comment: Нет никаких проблем запустить php-скрипт на круглосуточную работу, это делается так же как и в любых других языках

Comment: С этим тоже свои проблемы. Частенько скрипт дох, когда делал подобную реализацию. При этом вырубался 1 раз из 100 без ошибок, это дело нужно отлавливать, но счел, что просто не стоит делать подобную реализацию на php. По этой причине я не зря написал в первом пункте "без перебоев". Неужели нет хотя бы альтернатив cron'у с возможностью запуска условно каждые 5-10 секунд, а лучше каждую секунду?

Comment: Мне не известны причины, по которым современный php (версии 7 или новее) мог бы дохнуть сам по себе, так что подозреваю, что у вас php-скрипт сам по себе был кривой. Однако даже если он и дохнет, ничто не мешает сделать автоматический перезапуск скрипта/программы после подыхания, это поддерживается в любой нормальной системе инициализации (и это опять же не зависит от языка)